# Add rows based on a specific number in a cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am in the process of writing a macro that needs to be able add a number of rows based on COUNTIF formula.

```
 =COUNTIF(D2:D1000,">=1/1/2017")-COUNTIF(D2:D1000,">1/2/2018")
```

So essentially, I want to be able to put that formula on my destination sheet, use the formula to count all the times that a date appears within the range in my source spreadsheet, return the count and add new rows based on what the value is. The formula is accurate, its just in the wrong place at the moment (it's on the source spreadsheet, not the destination). I have the start of some code but I am struggling with where to go next to achieve my goal. Can anyone please help?

```
 Sub Map_To_Import_Sheet()

 Dim wbs As Workbook 'Source workbook
 Dim wbd As Workbook 'Destination workbook already open
 Dim ss As Worksheet 'Source worksheet
 Dim ds As Worksheet 'Destination worksheet

   Set wbd = ThisWorkbook
   Set wbs = Workbooks.Open("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
 (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\TimeSheet Templates\Copy of 
 MSI shifts 19th June - 25th June.xlsx")
   Set ss = wbs.Worksheets(1)
   Set ds = wbd.Worksheets("Import Sheet")

  'Removes the data from the columns A through R in NHSP Import Template 

   ds.Range(ds.Range("A4:R18"), 
  ds.Range("A4:R18").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

 'Counts the rows with data on the source spreadsheet and adds the 
  appropriate number to the destination (Import sheet)
  ss.Activate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instructions aren't descriptive yet, so I can't help too much. We'll discuss in the comments and I'll improve my answer as we go.

```
Sub Map_To_Import_Sheet()        
    Dim srcWb As Workbook 'Source workbook
    Dim destWb As Workbook 'Destination workbook already open
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet 'Source worksheet
    Dim destSht As Worksheet 'Destination worksheet

    Set destWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWb = Workbooks.Open("filepath")
    Set srcSht = srcWb.Worksheets(1)
    Set destSht = destWb.Worksheets("Import Sheet")

    'Removes the data from the columns A through R in NHSP Import Template
    '- Import Sheet
    destSht.Range(destSht.Range("A4:R18"), destSht.Range("A4:R18").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

    'Counts the rows with data on the source spreadsheet and adds the
    'appropriate number to the destination (Import sheet)
    Dim count As Integer
    count = srcSht.Range("cell formula location").Value
    srcSht.Range("cell formula location").Copy
    destSht.Range("new cell formula location").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    'MsgBox count 'prints out count

    'explain your insert more please
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please give an example sheet with the operations you would like to do? (Eg the formula is in cell A3 and needs to go into cell A5 of destSht. Then I want to insert x rows after row 6 on destSht based on the formula's value)